# How to exclude object entries for which given key is not in given array when mapping?

Tags: javascript

When mapping an object like below, how to exclude the ones for which the `value` is in the array `arr` ?

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar']
return Object.entries(myobject).map(
  ([value, text]) => ({
    text,
    value,
  })
)
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Array#filter`, to filter the keys which are in the `arr` array. The `Array#includes` will return a boolean indicating the presence or absence of the key in the `arr` array:

```js
const myobject = {
  hello: "world",
  bar: "bar",
  foo: "foo"
};
const arr = ['foo', 'bar']
const ent = Object.entries(myobject)
  .filter(([value]) => !arr.includes(value))
  .map(([value, text]) => ({
    text,
    value,
  }));
console.log(ent);
```